# How can I ensure correct padding in DES encryption?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, des

I am trying to implement a basic Diffie-Hellman protocol and the code succeeds up to the point when it needs to decrypt the sent value using DES. I have looked at a lot of examples in which it was a matter of the keys not matching up, but I am printing their values on both ends of the connection and they are both exactly the same. I have also tried multiple padding schemes as well as changing how the keys were generated.

My last attempt was in adding the parameter IvParameterSpec to the cipher init, but that only solved one of the errors.

I am running this on a single machine where the socket is connecting over the localhost and I have been checking for any issues on either side with the sent data not exactly matching the received data, but nothing is altered in the sending. I did notice, however, that when printing each of the byte arrays on either side of the socket that the client side is much longer than the server with what appears to be padding(?)

The error I am getting is saying that the final block is padded incorrectly and so decryption fails

My Server code (the side that is not working as intended):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;

    // Creates a connectable socket on port 6789
    try {
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(true){
        try{
            double k2, B, A;
            double n = 13;
            double g = 61;
            long y = 7;
            B = (Math.pow(g, y))%n;

            System.out.println("Accepting connections");
            // Accept an incoming connection on the socket server
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            // Creates a read and write stream for that client
            DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            // Sends the double to the client
            outToClient.writeDouble(B);
            System.out.println("Sent " + B);
            // Reads the number sent by the Client
            A = inFromClient.readDouble();
            System.out.println("Received " + A);

            // Modifies the number
            k2 = (Math.pow(A, y))%n;
            System.out.println("DES key seed = " + k2);
            byte[] deskeydata = toByteArray(k2);

            // Turns the bytes of the modified number into a DES key spec
            DESKeySpec deskeyspec = new DESKeySpec(deskeydata);

            // Makes a secret key (DES)
            SecretKeyFactory keyF = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey keystuff = keyF.generateSecret(deskeyspec);
            System.out.println(keystuff.toString());

            // Gets an incoming string from the client and turns it into binary
            byte[] incomingBytes = new byte[128];
            try{
                inFromClient.readFully(incomingBytes);
            } catch(EOFException eof){
                System.out.println("Finished reading");
            }
            System.out.println(new String(incomingBytes));
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            // Decrypts the string using the shared secret key
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keystuff, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]));
            byte[] ct2 = c.doFinal(incomingBytes);

            // Decode it from base 64
            //byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ct2);

            // Prints the received string
            System.out.println("Received: " + new String(ct2));

            inFromClient.close();
            outToClient.close();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My Client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creates a socket to the local host on port 6789
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        double k1, B, A;
        double n = 13;
        double g = 61;
        long x = 3;

        // Sends an unencrypted number to the server
        A = (Math.pow(g, x))%n;
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());  

        // Transforms A into a byte array and sends it over
        outToServer.writeDouble(A);
        outToServer.flush();
        System.out.println("Sending " + A);

        // Reads the incoming data from the server
        B = inFromServer.readDouble();
        System.out.println("Recieved " + B);

        // Modifies the data to create the number for des key
        k1 = (Math.pow(B, x))%n;
        System.out.println("DES key seed = " + k1);
        byte[] deskeydata = toByteArray(k1);

        // Turns the bytes of the modified number into a DES key spec
        DESKeySpec deskeyspec = new DESKeySpec(deskeydata);

        // Makes a secret key (DES)
        SecretKeyFactory keyF = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey keystuff = keyF.generateSecret(deskeyspec);
        System.out.println(keystuff.toString());

        // Takes in input from the user and turns it into binary
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a message:");

        String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        byte[] str2 = sentence.getBytes();
        byte[] encodedMessage = Base64.getEncoder().encode(str2);

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // Encrypts the user's input with the secret key
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keystuff, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]));
        byte[] ct2 = c.doFinal(encodedMessage);
        System.out.println("Initted the cipher and moving forward with " + new String(ct2));

        // Writes the encrypted message to the user
        outToServer.write(ct2);
        outToServer.flush();


        inFromServer.close();
        outToServer.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Anything that could help me in getting this working would be immensely welcome since I have been working on this error alone for quite some time.

Comment: can you be more specific than "not working as intended"? what is the actual error / unexpected result?

Comment: Adjusted the description. It's a badpaddingexception saying that the final block is padded incorrectly

Comment: You are writing an byte array of unknown and varying length on the client side. On the server side you are always reading 128 bytes. That mismatch is a likely source of bugs. There are also clearly other bugs, such as base64 encoding on the client but not decoding on the server side.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but I had done this exact thing earlier with an rsa encryptions string and ran into no issues at all assuming the string was smaller than the key. As far as the base64, I encoded it that way before encrypting it and the issue is that the encryption is failing, so the base64 shouldn't be affecting the error I'm currently getting. My thought was that the readFully function was stripping the padding from the transmission. Is that possible? Otherwise, the readfully just gets as many bytes as exist on the stream.

Comment: **Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the security risks but this is just for learning purposes. I'm supposed to break the cipher after this and that would be basically impossible with aes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out a way to solve this (though I suspect it is very inefficient). The issue was due to the readFully method on the server side. I was reading the answer into a 128 byte array and the decrypt function saw the empty slots in the byte array as something instead of nothing.

To solve this I replaced the input section with the following, which reads each individual byte and creates an array of bytes with the exact length of the incoming message.

```
            ArrayList<Byte> totalBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            while(true){
                try{
                    byte in = inFromClient.readByte();
                    totalBytes.add(in);
                } catch(EOFException eof){
                    System.out.println("Finished reading");
                    break;
                }
            }
            int incomingSize = totalBytes.size();
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[incomingSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < incomingSize; i++){
                receivedBytes[i] = totalBytes.get(i);
            }
```